# CKEditor Icons not showing up in firefox inconsistently

Tags: firefox, ckeditor

[image: http://i.imgur.com/m3VfmF5.png]. 
This is inconsistent and only appears to happen in firefox.  A refresh of the page will bring the icons when it does happen, and it leaves no errors or anything in the console.  The buttons do still work, but a client has been complaining about this.  Any help would be appreciated, my googling skills are usually up to par but I haven't seen a lot of people with a similar issue and am kinda stumped as is without any errors in the console to go by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CKEditor's high contrast mode. You can read more about it in the [CKEditor + WAI-ARIA = Usable Accessibility](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-WAI-ARIA-Usable-Accessibility) article.

It seems that for some reason CKEditor thinks that the operating system's high contrast mode is enabled so it enables its.

The detection code is here:
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/_bootstrap.js#L11-L38

Maybe it will give you some ideas why it may happen that on this specific page the HC mode is enabled. If not you can try executing this code right after the script tag which includes `ckeditor.js`:

```
CKEDITOR.env.hc = false;
CKEDITOR.env.cssClass = CKEDITOR.env.cssClass.replace( / cke_hc/, '' );
```

This should be able to switch HC mode off.